# Strange mouse events with display: flex and svg

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, flexbox

I came across some strange behavior when embedding a SVG element inside a DIV that has `display:flex.` Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaseNewmark/pe1zr63e/1/).
With `display: flex` on the container a mouse down event will only be captured by the `rect`. If you comment out the css and run again, the `svg` will also receive mouse down events.
Can somebody tell how to fix this? Might it be related to Angular?
BR,
Daniel

Comment: Seems fine to me on Firefox.

Comment: Seems fine in Chrome as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a chrome issue. I had 36.0.1985.143, when I encountered the problem. Now I have 37.0.2062.94 and everthing works fine.